# spring-boot: where is defined the settings to generate jar files

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jar

how (where) the spring-boot defines

1. the name of generated jar-files
2. the settings for jar-generation by `~$ mvn package` . There are two file generated by maven in target folder: XXXX.jar and XXXX.jar.origin.

How can i interfere with the jar-generation process?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

in your pom.xml

```
<build>
  <finalName>desiredname</finalName>
</build>
```

**or**

spring-boot typically uses [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html)

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
                        <finalName>yourdisiredname</finalName>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

then,

```
mvn package
```

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml (because you are using maven; otherwise if you are using gradle, then its build.gradle) can be used to control the jar file name.